# What is this soldier's regiment?

Tags: military, united-kingdom, identification

Could anyone please help me identify this soldier's regiment
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm if it is a British regiment as opposed to a Commonwealth regiment? Canada at least has its own Scottish regiments.

Comment: Well thank you for that Pieter, I did not think of that. I had relatives both in the UK and Canada who fought in The Boer Wars and WW1 and WW2 and this photo was in a family group of photos. My grandfather was in the Field Artillery but there were some of his family who went out to Canada and returned with the Expeditionary Force.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the socks pattern and what I can make out of the hat pin, this appears to be the [Argyll and Sutherland Highlanders of Canada (Princess Louise's)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Argyll_and_Sutherland_Highlanders_of_Canada_(Princess_Louise%27s)), pictured here during the funeral for [Corporal Nathan Cirillo](https://globalnews.ca/news/4581356/four-years-after-tragic-and-senseless-attack-cpl-nathan-cirillo-remembered/):

[image]

[Hi-Res Link](http://specphotos.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Gardner-Funeral10.jpg):

The claim is made in the comments that the cap badge here is different than shown on Wikipedia. Wikipedia is clearly in error here (or out of date). Here is a photograph of Cpl. Nathan Cirillo, of the *Argyll and Sutherland Highlanders of Canada (Princess Louise's)* standing guard in Ottawa prior to his murder. Note the cap badge.

[image]

Comment: That was my impression too but cannot think of anyone who was in that Regiment. I will have to dig deeper and see if there was someone I am missing.

Comment: I think it's the Argyll and Sutherland Regiment from Scotland. The cap badge is huge and that regiment had the largest cap badge in the British military. The badge in the old photo doesn't look anything like the five pointed badge of the Canadian version.

Comment: @Daniel: It appears Wikipedia is incorrect. See edit with picture of Cpl. Nathan Cirillo.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Check this [image](http://media.iwm.org.uk/ciim5/398/432/large_000000.jpg) please. It is an officer of the A&S from WWI. The cap badge shows the similarity to the one in the black and white photo here. Plus the canadian regiment of the same name has a hollow space in the middle of the badge which the old photo badge does not.

Comment: @Daniel: **Both images in this answer are of the *Argyll and Sutherland Highlanders of Canada (Princess Louise's)***. That is unequivocal. Both are from Canadian media - of Cpl. Nathan Cirillo standing guard at the Ottawa cenotaph, and of his regiment at his funeral in Hamilton ON. The socks for the British eponymous regiment are a simpler tartan, and with a much darker red. Check it out.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Yes, and both images show a cap badge different to the one in the original photo. I wouldn't get hung up on the diced hose as the Scottish highland regiments were wearing the same pattern as the man in the original photo back in WWI which is white background with red stripes and black squares where the stripes intersect.